# Remove space separator between awk printf / print

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

The following command format the `disk_space_in_bytes` variable into a human readable output, with 2 digits after the comma.

```
echo $disk_space_in_bytes | awk '{ suffix=" KMGT"; for(i=1; $1>1024 && i < length(suffix); i++) $1/=1024; printf("%.2f\n", $1); print(substr(suffix, i, 1)"B")}'
```

(Credit goes to @Innocent Bystander https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724130/6133648 for this awk command)

For example if `disk_space_in_bytes` is `858 458 685,44` (value in bytes), then the command will print `818.69 MB`, but with a space in between.

I would like to remove this extra space, for example `818,69MB`. But this get a little bit to tricky for me in awk. I tried some ORS and OFS manipulation without success.

Can you find way to remove the extra space ?

Thanks

Comment: see also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854332/file-size-in-human-readable-format... for example: `numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --format="%.2f" 858458685.44`

Comment: And what have **you** tried? StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Best to show your failed attempts so we can help improve your understanding of `awk` et.al. .  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @BenjaminW. The space in the suffix is for the case when ``disk_in_space_in_bytes`` is lower than 1024 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724130/6133648 comments).

Comment: @shellter As I said in the original post, I tried to set ``ORS=""`` (Output Record Separator) and ``OFS=""`` (Output Field Separator), hoping to supress the space after the printf. It didn't work and I felt that this was probably not the way to achieve that. I'll have a look at those links and keep in mind your advice for my next questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the parameters of the `awk` command as shown below. Currently, it has an extra linebreak after the byte count, and it also still prints a space in `" KMGT"`, but that space is necessary for the way that particular `awk` command displays the right denomination of bytes.

This command assumes you are using the `gawk` variant, as it uses the `gawk`-specific function `gensub`.

```
echo $disk_space_in_bytes | awk '{ suffix=" KMGT"; for(i=1; $1>1024 && i < length(suffix); i++) $1/=1024; printf("%.2f", $1); print(gensub(/ /, "", "g", substr(suffix, i, 1))"B")}'
```

Shown in pieces to make it make more sense:

```
echo $disk_space_in_bytes |
  awk '{
    suffix=" KMGT";
    for(i=1; $1>1024 && i < length(suffix); i++)
      $1/=1024;
    printf("%.2f", $1);
    print(gensub(/ /, "", "g", substr(suffix, i, 1))"B")
  }'
```

Basically, there are just two changes here:

- Line break (`\n`) removed from the `printf` command
- The `gensub` command as used here strips whitespace off of the suffix that gets appended to the byte denomination, which is a space if it is bytes, and not kilobytes or so on.

Comment: @EdMorton Oversight on my part, thank you for bringing that up. Edited the answer.

Comment: The line break was indeed the culprit, thank you for noticing it. Nice for the gensub.